# Echoing php div on submit

Tags: php, css, forms, echo

**UPDATE** I am trying to echo a div after info is submitted on a contact form. My website is here: http://tinyurl.com/bdmhv7u

When you click on rsvp and enter the information, I have a graphic that I would like to be shown. Using this code, it shows, but only for an instant. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
<?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            include("process.php");
            unset($_POST['submit']);
     } else  {

     }
        ob_flush();
    ?>

<div id="gotit">
<div id="gotitimg">
<img src="images/gotit.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$("#submit").click(function (event) {  
  $("#gotit").fadeIn(1000, function() {
  });
});
</script> 

#gotit {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    margin-top:400px;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
}

#gotitimg {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: should i use little js for above requirement?

Comment: anything that will help me get this- thanks! I've been researching all morning

Comment: you just have to display that particular div on the right side of the submit button? but the form will redirect it to some other page! are you using AJAX or something?

Comment: No, I am not using ajax- I have a file that processes the info and emails the information

Comment: well, i said when i'll click the submit button then the page will redirect to other page, so, adding a div will not good idea! wanna use some jQuery? it will remain on the same page, shows the div and also register them! and your file is php which processes info?

Comment: sorry buddy i was busy and i think you got solution below ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> $("#submit").click(function () { $("#gotit").fadeIn(1000).delay(3000); }); </script>`

Comment: see that above works or not! you can increase time by changing that 3000 with any value e.g. 10000

Comment: No, the delay did not work. The image only lasts as long as it takes for the submit to be processed- (once the browser loading icon to disappears it's gone)

Comment: see this : http://jsfiddle.net/AQ5E2/

here i wrote some code try that one and change #myform with id or class of your form!

Comment: thanks- the image shows, but the form is not being processed. I changed "myform with #form, my form id and placed the script beneath the div.

Comment: what is name of php file?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the code, but you can try to add width and height to your div:
example

```
  #gotit {
  float:right;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px; 
  background-image:url(../gotit.png);
  position:fixed;
  z-index:20;
  margin-top:50px;
  }
```